# vertical-align doesn't center the text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following css:

```
#header-notification 
{
    color: #7B6F60;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
```

and declared the label as:

```
  <label id="header-notification"></label>
```

However doing so gives me the following:

[image]

As you can see the text here is not vertically centered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe `vertical-align` is used for images and or inputs. It doesn't have an effect on just simple text elements

Answer (score 3):

As you are using a single character to align it vertically, you can use `line-height` property here to vertically align in the middle of the element

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/khak6/)

```
#header-notification {
    color: #7B6F60;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

For making `vertical-align: middle;` work, you need to use `display: table-cell;` so that it will align middle vertically.. but you won't need that here as I specified that you are trying to align a single character. `display: table-cell;` method is generally used when you want to align an entire paragraph or an image vertically inside an element.

Comment: `vertical-align: center`? Did you mean `text-align: center` or `vertical-align: middle`?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a spin: http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/7zwUc/

You need to place it inside a parent div. (If you want to use vertical-align on it. Obviously there's other ways to do it).

HTML:

```
<div id="header-notification"> 
    <label id="number">0</label>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-notification 
{
    color: #7B6F60;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;

    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#number {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display: table-cell` for element:

```
#header-notification 
{
    display: table-cell;
    color: #7B6F60;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align:` *"Applies to: inline-level and 'table-cell' elements "*, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align